# How can I point an arrow at an object in Aframe?

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, virtual-reality

I need to point an arrow at an object in an Aframe scene. Both the arrow and object will be at arbitrary locations. The arrow will always begin pointing "up" along the z-axis. I have some ideas that are commented in the snippet below, but I'm not sure how to pull it off. Anyone know?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello, WebVR! • A-Frame</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Hello, WebVR! • A-Frame">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <a-scene background="color: #ECECEC">
      <a-sphere id="sphere" position="6 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
      
      <a-entity id="arrow"></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
  
  <footer>
    <script>
      const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
      loader.load("https://cdn.glitch.com/6ff6d9d5-f662-48cc-8e22-30eaf4dfc295%2Farrow.glb?v=1612557642197", function ( model ) {
          model.scene.traverse(node => {
              if (node.geometry && node.material) {
                  geometry = node.geometry;
              }
          })
          geometry.scale( .5,.5,.5 );
          geometry.computeVertexNormals();

          material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ flatShading: true, color: 0xFF0000 });
          mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        
          document.getElementById('arrow').object3D.add(mesh);
        
          const arrow = document.getElementById('arrow').object3D;
          arrow.position.set(1,1,1);
        
          const sphere = document.getElementById('sphere').object3D;
          
          // this angleTo method from Three js seems promising. 
          // Unfortunately, it returns only one angle. I guess its the angle along 
          // the plane of the vectors. There is also a rotateAlongAxis function. 
          // If I could find the axis connecting the arrow and sphere, maybe 
          // I could apply this angle to the arrow and it would work. 
          const ang = new THREE.Vector3(arrow.position.x, arrow.position.y, arrow.position.z).angleTo(new THREE.Vector3(sphere.position.x, sphere.position.y, sphere.position.z));
        
          arrow.rotation.set(--need to determine these angles--);

      });
          
      
    </script>
  </footer>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You’ll need the `.lookAt()` method so your arrow is always pointing at the position you provide:

```
var position = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
arrow.lookAt(position);
```

Just make sure the arrow is pointing “forward” in the -z axis. If the position changes, just call the method again with the updated vector.

https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.lookAt

Comment: I see what you're saying and this is a solution. I would have to edit the gltf model to be pointing down the -z-axis